# How to link Post Title to uploaded file?

Tags: posts, title

I’ve added a file upload field (post_pdf) using ACF Pro for Posts.

Show this field group if Post Type is equal to Post

Some posts will be for content entered into the editor… many posts however will just be links to a PDF.

Would like the Post Title to link to the uploaded PDF (_blank) if it exists, otherwise link to the normal post content.

I assume this would be a function (in functions.php), with a check to see if( get_field('post_pdf') ): isset and !empty then link post title to file, else link to post?

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: ACF Pro Field for PDF]